# Swift Firebase 4.0 - observeSingleEvent not returning data set (but authentication is working)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have been working with Firebase on Android for the last 12 months+, with  success. I just switched over to Swift and am attempting to read data from the same Firebase database I created and have been using the last 12 months+. Since there is security applied to the FB DB the first thing I did  was to get FB authentication (from Swift) working. This works. Now, I am trying to get a simple observeSingleEvent operational and am struggling.

The Firebase DB is the same old stuff. It has a users node off of the root. For starters I would just like to read in a user from the user's node. I know authentication is working because when I submit my email and password I receive a confirmation. When the email / password are wrong I do not get confirmation. Given this validates my connection to the DB and as a test I stuck the following code in right after login validation.

When I debug this it simply skips from the "self.ref?.child("users").observeSingleEvent..." to the bracket below. i.e. It never acknowledges there is data available, but there is data available.

To avoid anyone asking "What do you need?" What I am looking for is an answer to why I receive no data result set with the code below given there is data in the FB DB and I have been reading/writing that data on Android for the last 12+ months.

Any/all help is welcome as I cut my teeth on Swift / FB 4.0

```
@IBAction func signInButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // TODO: Do some form validation on the email and password

    if let email = emailTextField.text, let pass = passwordTextField.text {

        // Check if it's sign in or register
        if isSignIn {
            // Sign in the user with Firebase
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: pass, completion: { (user, error) in

                // Check that user isn't nil
                if let u = user {
                    // User is found, go to home screen

                    self.ref = Database.database().reference()
                    self.ref?.child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {( snapshot) in
                        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                        let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""
                        print ("***   " + username)

                    })           
                }
                else {
                    // Error: check error and show message
                }

            })

        }
```

Comment: `print(username)` doesnt execute?

Comment: Thanks - it compiles with no errors. I can then run it. Given I never received any output from the print statement I put a breakpoint at "self.ref?"...It gets there and skips to the next bracket.

Comment: ok pleasee try add `print("inside ref")`  after `print(username)` and then run the program without any break points and see if it prints

Comment: Thanks - inside ref printed in the debug output. What is this telling me?

Comment: ok good, since `observeSingleEvent` is an async call so it is running on the background thread, that is why it jumps on to the next bracket when you put a break point on `self.ref`, because it doesnt block the current thread of execution and does execute after sometime on background thread

Comment: Ugh that makes perfect sense. Thank you. So how in Swift may I "Catch" the asynch return? I know how to do this in Android. I am not interested in putting a widget on the viewcontroller/storyboard. Debug output is fine.

Comment: I have added the answer where use completion handler to get the data from an async call, here I am only fetching username  but you can return other data as well, have a look, see if it helps you

Comment: Thanks I implemented the function you prescribed below. I also changed the print user statement (edited above) to include "***    " + user. print ("inside ref") follows this in the func. The first *** prints but with nothing else on the line. The inside ref prints on the next line. This tells me I am getting nothing back. In android I usually specify the URL to the FB node I am seeking. I don't do that here in Swift. I assume FB assumes my root is the top most node?

Comment: Please add `print("Snapshot : \(snapshot)")` and see what are you getting from the database

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere, thank you. I get my data!! I get the key value = {".priority" = "user email address"; ".value" = username;}; So I guess the part that's not working is assigning NSDictionary and the assignment of username = value?...? So how do I assign the key/value pair to just a simple string or strings in swift so they will print out?

Comment: I have edited my answer, see if it helps you, see if `print(value)` prints the correct data?

Comment: It prints the correct data. Perfect, thank you very much. I will now read up on [String: Any] to understand what it is doing. I do not immediately understand how you fixed it. But you definitely fixed it. Thanks again.

Comment: `NSDictionary` is objective c style dictionary, whereas `[String: Any]` is swift style dictionary  , I would suggest try to avoid using `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` in swift , check this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: Thank you I will review that link. One last question, if I should open another stack question just let me know. I intend to replicate my Android / FIrebase app to Swift / Firebase to support both platforms. My first critical test of Swift / FB is storing dates. On Android / Java I use the Java-native Date and store that in Firebase. What FB does with that is store all the date parts (month, date, hour, minute, etc) as separate attributes in the node. FB also stores "Time" (long utc) as an attribute. I am seeking the common denominator date between Android / IoS. Will it be the Long UTC?

Comment: Sorry Frank, I am afraid I cant help you there since I donot have much experience about date storage in FB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since observeSingleEvent is an async call so it is running on the background thread, that is why it jumps on to the next bracket when you put a break point on self.ref, because it doesnt block the current thread of execution and does execute after sometime on background thread

One way to do is this:

```
@IBAction func signInButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // TODO: Do some form validation on the email and password

    if let email = emailTextField.text, let pass = passwordTextField.text {

        // Check if it's sign in or register
        if isSignIn {
            // Sign in the user with Firebase
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: pass, completion: { (user, error) in

                // Check that user isn't nil
                if let u = user {
                    // User is found, go to home screen

                    self.fetchUserName { fetchedUserName in
                        print(fetchedUserName)

                    }        
                }
                else {
                    // Error: check error and show message
                }

            })

        }

func fetchUserName(completionHandler: @escaping (String) -> Void) {


      self.ref = Database.database().reference()
      self.ref?.child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {( snapshot) in
            //let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                  print(value)
                  let username = value["username"] as? String ?? ""

                  print (username)
                  completionHandler(username)

            }

      })


}
```